# Sklearn precision recall curve pos_label for unbalanced dataset which class probability to use

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

i want to evaluate my model using the precision recall scores, because my data is unbalanced. Since I have a binary classification I am using a softmax at the end of my NN.
The output scores and true labels look something like :

```
y_score = [[0.4, 0.6],
           [0.6, 0.4],
           [0.3, 0.7],
              ...   ]
y_true = [1,
          0,
          0,
         ...]
```

Where `y_score[:,0]` corresponds to the probability of class 0.
My *positive labels* are **0** and thus the *negative labels* are **1** in my case.

Since my dataset is unbalanded (more negatives than positives) I want to use the precision recall score (AUPRC) to evaluate my classifier. The function `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve` takes a parameter `pos_label`, which I would set to `pos_label = 0`. But the parameter `probas_pred`
takes an ndarray of probabilities of shape (n_samples,).

My question is, which of my `y_score` column should I take for `probas_pred` since I set `pos_label = 0`?

I hope my question is clear.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the first column in the example above, here's how you can check to be sure.

Using an example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=[400,2000], centers=None,n_features=5,random_state=999,cluster_std=5)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=111)
```

Train the classifier:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(3, 3), random_state=999)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Check the classes:

```
clf.classes_
array([0, 1])
```

You can put it together on the dataframe to see that it's correct:

```
    0   1   actual
0   0.999734    0.000266    0
1   0.001253    0.998747    1
2   0.000137    0.999863    1
3   0.000113    0.999887    1
4   0.003173    0.996827    1
... ... ... ...
475 0.014316    0.985684    1
476 0.012767    0.987233    1
477 0.062735    0.937265    1
478 0.000048    0.999952    1
479 0.999733    0.000267    0
```

Then calculate it:

```
prec,recall,thres = precision_recall_curve(y_true=y_test , probas_pred= clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0], pos_label=0)
```

And plot it.. if you flipped your values, this will look really weird, but below its correct:

```
plt.plot(prec,recall)
```

[image]